# Android: What is the bin/res/crunch folder used for?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

While modifying a white label app, I needed to change a logo and found it was located in 2 locations (duplicated):

- `res/drawable` and similar folders (for other screen depths)
- `bin/res/crunch/drawable` and similar folders (for other screen depths)

So I would like to know if I should care about the second folder, or if it's something  generated by Eclipse/ADT.

Comment: don't care about these. they are build-generated. Crunch means that these files are re-compressed by a process from the android toolkit.

Comment: @njzk2, Re-compressed? Meaning?

Comment: @Pacerier: my understanding is that all resources are processed by the build tools, and the images in drawables are compressed to a format that suits android better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are automatically generated on build. You can ignore them.

Comment: I recently run into a problem with this folder. After I changed my app icons, I surprisingly saw that Android would show the older version of the icon on my device. After struggling a bit, I noticed that the crunch folder was not properly updated, and that the icons in that folder were the older ones. I removed the folder, cleaned the project and that fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

The crunch is used to export the app by eclipse and I've experienced a problem that a drawable was not updated in a crunch. If you want to be really sure that you deliver what you see, just clean the res/crunch/drawable before exporting.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, i believe that this is because of import from one machine to another one. (mostly, like 64-bit to 32-bit)

Just delete the folder crunch... activity will run fine.